# Computing limits example: Swaping limit to $0$ into infinity.

Tags: calculus, limits

I have found the following example:
$$
  \lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{e^{\frac{-1}{h}}}{h} = 
  \lim_{z\to\infty} ze^{-z} = 
  0 
$$

Could you explain to a kid nice and slowly why does the limit of $x$ to $0$ now is limit of $z$ to $\infty$?

P.S. I know how to compute the limit from the left, I just found in the solution book this solution from the right which I found strange and is unknown to me.

Comment: What do you get when you plug in $h=0.001$ on the left? What do you get when you plug in $z=1000$ on the right?

Comment: Also, typo, that's supposed to be $h\to0^+$ on the left. There are no $x$s in the limit on the left.

Answer (score 3):

It is a substitution of $z := \frac{1}{h}$. So when $h\to 0^+$ we have that $z\to \infty$.